# Update Layout view from other activity

Tags: android, android-layout

I have this service class

```
public TouchService(Context ctx, View v, WindowManager wm) {
    ctx = mContext;
    v = touchLayout;
    wm = mWindowManager;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    prefs = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(TouchService.this);
    int index = prefs.getInt("position choise", 0);
    int triggerWidth = prefs.getInt("width choise", 14);
    int triggerHeight = prefs.getInt("height choise", 300);
    int triggerPosLeft = prefs.getInt("posLeft choise", 300);
    int triggerPosRight = prefs.getInt("posRight choise", 300);

    touchLayout = new LinearLayout(TouchService.this);

    int triggerColor = prefs.getInt("trigger color",
            (getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent)));
    touchLayout.setBackgroundColor(triggerColor);
    touchLayout.setOnTouchListener(this);
    vibe = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);

    mWindowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);


    mParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            triggerWidth, // width of layout
            triggerHeight, // height of layout
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE, // Type Phone, These are non-application windows providing user interaction with the phone (in particular incoming calls).
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE, // this window won't ever get key input focus
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

    switch (index) {
        case 0:
            mParams.gravity = Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.TOP;
            mParams.y = triggerPosLeft;

            break;

        case 1:
            mParams.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT | Gravity.TOP;
            mParams.y = triggerPosRight;
            break;


    }

    Log.i(TAG, "add View");
    mWindowManager.addView(touchLayout, mParams);
}
```

I want to update the view from an activity class to **change its background color without restarting the service. **

Here is the related code of control activity:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    editor.putInt("trigger color",
            (getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent)));
    editor.commit();
    tservice = new TouchService(mContext, touchLayout, wm);


    this.finish();
    return true;
}
```

I created the constructor on service class and a new instance of `TouchService` in control activity, but I don't know how to get access to the view to change the background color. I made some tries, but I always get nullPointerException or cannot find Resource id.
How do Iaccess this layout?

Comment: Does the service runs the same process (it doesn't have android:process attribute defined)? Could you clarify if your intention is to change some activties view background from Service? If so, why do you need it? Services usually handles different tasks, for interactions with UI there's AsyncTask.

Comment: No, I want to change the view's color from 2 other activities. The view is defined in service as transparent. I want to change the color, so to be termporarly visible to the user, to change size and position from another activity. So I want to change the background from other activities not from service.

Comment: Then why not just send intent to that activity? Activity which holds view is not visible, then you're trying to change view background, so you can send intent to it or set shared preferences and just analyze it onResume().

Comment: You confused me a bit. The view is on service, and is visible I think(just with transparent background) because the service is running. Send intent from service or from activity? Can you give some example code?

Comment: Send intent from activtiy which should change view. E.g. easiest way - to have IntentService implemented.